# I am removing a method from the onClickListener and call it seperately, and then it's causing problem

Tags: java, android

I have an android app where I am clicking a button to take the current location. However that button is calling a method which does the trick. So now I want to remove the method from that onClickListener method and call it seperately at the beginning of the project. My code when it was under the onClickListener

```
binding.buttonConfirmPickup.setOnClickListener(view -> onButtonConfirmPickupClicked());
```

But whenever I commenting out this line of code and call the `onButtonConfirmPickupClicked()` method it's throwing nullpointerexception.

Here's my Logcat.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mostain.taxi.rider/com.mostain.taxi.rider.activities.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getCameraPosition()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getCameraPosition()' on a null object reference
        at com.mostain.taxi.rider.activities.main.MainActivity.onButtonConfirmPickupClicked(MainActivity.java:472)
        at com.mostain.taxi.rider.activities.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:212)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7088)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7079)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
```

So how come it works when under the onClick method but doesn't works outside of it?

Comment: Your error is indicating that your `GoogleMap` instance has not been initialized. Hence the null ptr exception. It has nothing to do with click listeners

Comment: @Christilyn But whenever it's under that onClick method it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: As @christilyn mentioned it is nothing to do with the click listener. While you invoke/call onButtonConfirmPickupClicked  outside the click listener ,at that time your map object is not yet initialized ,and system does not have the map object , so null pointer exception thrown. But if you put onButtonConfirmPickupClicked inside the click listener, before clicking that button/view map object is initialized/might be visible, so it works fine.

Comment: Can you guys suggest a workaround like how can I initialize the map object before this to happened? @Oooha

Comment: when you call the  `getMapAsync `, you will be getting the `onMapReady` callback which indicates map object is initialized. Then, you can enable your view clickable/making the view visible after you got the callback.It really depends on your use case.Additionally you could also check whether the google play services installed on the device before enabling your view, because it is essential for the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) method of OnMapReadyCallback interface give you GoogleMap object. initialise your map object with this object and try to call onButtonConfirmPickupClicked() after that.

Comment: Thanks, though I tried what you said before you said anything, it worked for me. Thanks a lot.